# Run dockerize a Laravel (Php) App for container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I want to dockerize my laravel learning app and have been unable to find simple tutorial that runs without errors. Each one is different and fails so I created my own. Here is how my Dockerfile look like, my first attempt

```
# stage 1: start from composer
FROM composer:2.6.5 as build
WORKDIR /app

# copy all the code
COPY . .

# run composer to update
RUN composer update --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-interaction --ignore-platform-req=ext-http --ignore-platform-req=ext-xdebug

# stage 2: get the php latest image
FROM php:8.3.0RC6-zts-bullseye as production

# update the image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl libpng-dev libonig-dev libxml2-dev

# add necessary libraries
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# clean the apt cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

# copy all code from stage 1
COPY --from=build /app /var/www/html

# move the production file to the image
COPY .env.production .env

# RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN php artisan config:cache && \
    php artisan route:cache && \
    chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/storage/ && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ && \

ENTRYPOINT ["php", "artisan", "serve", "-host 0.0.0.0", "-port 8080" ]
```

Needsless to say it failed at various steps specially when setting permissions for directories in container. Also libraries could not be installed for instance

- mbstring
- gd

So i gave up on the idea of creating it myself and used ChatGPT to generate one for me, I had to modify it though as before the default one failed again.

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM php:8.3.0RC6-cli as builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy Laravel application files
COPY . .

# Install dependencies using composer
RUN composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-suggest --ignore-platform-req=ext-http --ignore-platform-req=ext-xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
#RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
#RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Generate an optimized autoloader
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --classmap-authoritative

# Generate the application key
RUN php artisan key:generate

# Build the application
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache
#RUN php artisan view:cache

# Stage 2: Create final image
FROM php:8.3.0RC6-cli

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app .

# Expose the application port (if needed)
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application
CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]
```

With this, although with changes, the app ran but was unable to do much. it kept on giving error:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "could not find driver (Connection: storage, SQL: select exists(select * from `role` where `roleid` = 7) as `exists`)"
}
```

I ran bash inside container and this is what I got when i did php --ini

```
root@c0c440c243bb:/app# php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/mysqli (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/mysqli.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/pdo_mysql (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20230831/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

As you can see, it's not able to access pdo-mysql, although it was defined. infact, there was no php.ini inside container, only php.ini.development and php.ini.production files in /usr/local/etc/php. I cp'ied the php.ini.production to php.ini in the same folder i.e. /usr/local/etc/php but again it didn't work. and I don't know if this error is fixed, what other errors would be there.

can anyone help me run the laraval app inside please?

dockerizing the laravel app and it didn't work

Comment: you could try Laravel Sail?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I don't know much about that. is it some docker image

Comment: Laravel sail is a pre set docker image for development great for beginners. You can do `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash` will create a fresh laravel installation named `example-app` plus docker image and containers or `composer require laravel/sail --dev` + `php artisan sail:install` to install on existing app. Both needs `./vendor/bin/sail up` to start the docker.

Answer (score 0):

I create a basic dockerfile to run your app you can learn from this.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2.0 as php

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bc math
RUN pecl install -o -f redis && rm -rf /tmp/pear && docker-php-ext-enable redis

COPY --from=composer:2.3.5 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer 

WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "docker/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

docker/entrypoint.sh

```
if [ ! -f "vendor/autoload.php" ]; then
  composer install
fi

if [ ! -f ".env" ]; then
   cp .env.example .env
fi

php artisan migrate
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan serve --port=8000 --host=0.0.0.0 --env=.env
exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
   container_name: app
   build: #
    context: .
    target: php 
   working_dir: /var/www/app 
   volumes: 
    - ./:/var/www/app
   ports: 
    - 8000:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

````
FROM php:8.1-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
#    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx \
    cron \
    supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
COPY --from=node /app/node_modules /var/www/node_modules
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm
COPY docker/run.sh /var/www/docker/run.sh

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www
COPY .env.example .env

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage
# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
# RUN cp docker/ssl_certs.crt  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl_certs.crt
# RUN cp docker/ssl_key.key  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl_key.key
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
#RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN cp docker/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default


# Deployment steps
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh

### These commands will only execute once in production
### For development if db data is not important then we can execute these commands on every build.
RUN php artisan key:generate
# RUN yes | php artisan migrate:fresh
# RUN php artisan migrate
# RUN yes | php artisan db:seed
RUN php artisan passport:install --force
RUN php artisan queue:restart
#RUN php artisan tenants:artisan migrate
####
RUN touch /var/www/storage/logs/laravel-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
# RUN chmod 777 /var/www/storage/logs/laravel-*
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/storage/logs
RUN chgrp -R www-data /var/www/storage /var/www/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/storage /var/www/bootstrap/cache
#COPY CRONtab
ADD docker/root /etc/cron.d/log-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/log-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN touch /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/storage
RUN php artisan storage:link
RUN echo "request_terminate_timeout = 180" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
#RUN apt-get install cron -y
RUN service cron start
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/log-cron
# EXPOSE 80
# ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
EXPOSE 82
ENTRYPOINT php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0    ```
````

Comment: what is run.sh in the Dockerfile?

Comment: this line is commented in provided code. But some time we have run.sh file in our docker folder in our project to run any command then we use this